# Last cell in tableview not fully displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using [LeveyPopListView](https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView) and the last cell in the table is not fully displayed.

Help will be very much appreciated.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aianLee,

Set the TableView height in LeveyPopListView properly. It seems that the tableView height is greater than the parent view's height, hence your cell inside the LeveyPopListView's tableview is not positioning in the visible area. Logically the cell is in the bounds of tableView, hence the system is not brining it up. Change the tableView height.

Comment: yeah..tableview's height bigger than leveypoplistview's height...
thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your *tableview height* is greater than *tableview.superview's* height

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView height is greater than its superview's height. Use below code so that your tableView adjusts its height in all screen sizes.

```
[self.tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller is probably adjusting scroll view insets. Go to the project's storyboard and select the view controller where you are adding the table, and uncheck the option **Adjust Scroll View Insets**

[image]

Comment: Not the table but the view controller where you're adding the table.